# Конфигурирование Gradle. Как задать пользовательские параметры в build task

Tags: java, gradle, build

В моем проекте я задаю параметры в `VM Options`. Для запуска приложения в `Run VM options` ставлю `-Ddeveloper=true -Dversion=0`. Для тестирования и билдинга мне необходимо в зависимости от ситуации ставить в классе `SomeClass.java` специальные параметры

```
    public static final int TESTS_VERS = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("version"));
    public static final boolean DEVELOP_USE = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("developer"));
```

Для тестирования в build.gradle я задаю эти свойства.

Для `task test`:

```
test {
    systemProperty('version', '411')
    systemProperty('developer', 'true')
}
```

При выполнении в Gradle `task build` мне необходимо изменять эти параметры на 
  {`version`: `0`,`developer`:`false`}

Я пробовал изменить их

```
build{
    System.properties.setProperty("version", "0")
    System.properties.setProperty("developer", "true")
}
```

не получилось.

Как мне при выполнении `task build` изменять эти параметры?.

Может есть какой-то еще способ получше чтоб можно было изменять параметры в зависимости от конфигурации?

Answer (score 1):

У Gradle имеется другой инструмент, называется BuildConfig, вот что пишет об этом мануал:

> At build time, Gradle generates the BuildConfig class so your app code can inspect information about the current build. You can also add custom fields to the BuildConfig class from your Gradle build configuration file using the buildConfigField() method and access those values in your app's runtime code. Likewise, you can add app resource values with resValue().

Правда, он реализован [в виде плагина](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=buildconfig), при этом для Android это плагин уже [включен из коробки](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips).

При наличии BuildConfig, можно в `build.gradle` использовать такие декларации:

```
buildConfigField 'boolean', 'TEST', true
```

и далее в Java тексте к нему обратиться так:

```
if(BuildConfig.TEST) {
     //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Подскажите как это связать с Run/Debug VM Options ?

Comment: `BuildConfig.DEBUG=true/false`